# Why is my new Legrand Radiant smart dimmer switch not dimming?

Tags: electrical, lighting, dimmer-switch

I need help figuring out why my new smart dimmer switch’s dimming function is not working. I followed the installation instructions from the manual exactly. I am replacing a regular light switch with the smart dimmer so I can dim my kitchen lights.

This dimmer is in a box with 2 other light switches: one switch controls the under-cabinet lighting and the other controls a hallway light.

I found the hot, load, and ground wires and connected those to the appropriate wires on the dimmer. This dimmer requires a white neutral wire. The old switch was not using a white wire. I found a bundle of white wires in the box all joined together and capped. I removed the wire cap and connected the white wire coming from the dimmer to the entire bundle of white wires and reinstalled the wire cap.

I then flipped the breaker back on and tested the switch. The lights turn on and off perfectly. However the dimmer function does not work at all. Thinking it may be the light bulbs, I swapped all four out with four other bulbs that I’m sure are dimmable because I tested them first in my dining room dimmable light fixture. Same problem. Dimming function does not work.

I’ve attached a few photos of the box configuration. From left to right, the switches are as follows:

1. New Legrand Radiant smart dimmer;
2. Hallway light;
3. Under-cabinet lights.

Why is the dimming function not working?

Box configuration

[image]

Back of new dimmer:
[image]

Instructions
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out finally after trying different bulbs. I finally registered the smart switch and downloaded the Smart Lights app. I was playing with the settings and when I changed the phase from “forward” to “reverse,” the dimmer function started working (see photo below). I wish Legrand would have that somewhere in a FAQ but it’s website is not useful at all.

[image]